# Linux USB/Serial port won't create a tty device in /dev

Tags: linux, usb

I am connecting a USB to serial driver port to my system and I get about halfway to where I need to go.  When it is plugged in `dmesg` indicates:

```
<6>usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using sl811-hcd and address 4
<6>usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

and `lsusb`

```
Bus 2 Device 4: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 2 Device 1: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 1 Device 1: ID 0000:0000
```

I get a series of `usbdev2.4` (`usbdev2.4`, `usbdev2.4_ep00`, etc) devices in dev but no `ttyUSB0` or anything that I can open with minicom.

How do I get the system to create the `/dev` device?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Tough it may belong on superuser.  It's one computer and USB isn't generally used in server systems, at least not in this way.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2):

```
<6>usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using sl811-hcd and address 4
<6>usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

The messages above only indicate you have the basic USB support loaded in your kernel.

I guess you don't have the *usb-serial* kernel module loaded. What does `lsmod | grep serial` return?

What distribution are you using? And is the kernel the one bundled with the distribution or have you compiled your own?